# Differences between scapy.sr and scapy.srp

Tags: python, scapy

I'm using Scapy to scan my network and I can't see a differences between functions : 
**scapy.sr()** and **scapy.srp()**. Documentation says that **scapy.sr()** returns packets from *layer 3* and **scapy.srp()** returns packets from *layer 2*. What are these layers? Sorry for my question, I'm a beginner in networks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s a cool image that sums it up pretty well:

[image: Layers 2 & 3]

When you use `srp`, `srp1` or `sendp`, you are expected to provide a packet that starts at layer 2, such as:

```
srp1(Ether()/IP(dst="www.google.com")/ICMP())
```

Without the `p`, it’s layer 3:

```
sr1(IP(dst="www.google.com")/ICMP())
```

(Behind the scenes, Scapy takes care of it)

Layer 2 allows you to spoof the data link (Ethernet, 802.11...) frames, but it requires you to know which one to use.

Comment: Shouldn't `without the p` be: `srp1(IP(dst="www.google.com")/ICMP())` ?

Comment: Yeah my bad I copy pasted the previous line. Fixed