# What is the difference between sr and srp? Scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I don't understand the differences between sr and srp in scapy. pls explain it to me.
One more thing, how do I send an echo request with ICMP?

```py
packet = IP(dst='8.8.8.8')/ICMP()/Raw("dwasdwas")
sent_packet = sr1(packet,timeout = 1)
sent_packet.show()
```

Does this code need to use srp or sr?
And why dont I get echo reply?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at this : [Differences between scapy.sr and scapy.srp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55176879/differences-between-scapy-sr-and-scapy-srp)?

Comment: The answer to your second question is also on this page: you use `srp` when you craft an ethernet, wifi, ... (i.e., a level 2 payload) frame and `sr` when you craft an IP packet. So here you need to use `sr`.

Comment: For your last question there can be many reasons for not getting a reply (timeout, host temporarily down, ...).  But it does not seem related to your code: I tried it on my computer and it worked fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.